# Integrating Microsoft Identity Platform with a Python web application (MS Graph/Flask)

Tags: python, azure, flask, microsoft-graph-api

I'm following this instruction: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp
Afterwards, I get the following error:

```
 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jan/2021 10:13:10] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
[2021-01-21 10:13:11,175] ERROR in app: Exception on /login [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anndenisova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\anndenisova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\anndenisova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\anndenisova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\anndenisova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\anndenisova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "<ipython-input-1-12be0f08b757>", line 31, in login
    return render_template("login.html", auth_url=session["flow"]["auth_uri"], version=msal.__version__)
  File "C:\Users\anndenisova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 138, in render_template
    ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "C:\Users\anndenisova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 930, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "C:\Users\anndenisova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 883, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Users\anndenisova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 857, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "C:\Users\anndenisova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 115, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "C:\Users\anndenisova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 60, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "C:\Users\anndenisova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 89, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: login.html
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jan/2021 10:13:11] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

What can be wrong? I've edited the app_config.py file so that there would be my credentials. The  http://127.0.0.1:5000/ link won't work, I get the following:
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing a template as the error describes `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: login.html`, the `login.html` file is missing, so if your following the provided example, you should notice that there is a `templates` directory at a root and inside it there is HTML templates and the one you need `login.html` > https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp/tree/master/templates

Comment: Glad to hear that! p.s. If this answer has helped you to resolve the issue, accept the answer so that others would see that it's answered :) Thanks!